# Where can I find what driver packages are needed for specific RPi models?

Tags: firmware, pi-gen

The basic -lite image installs the following (and more) packages:

`wpasupplicant wireless-tools firmware-atheros firmware-brcm80211 firmware-libertas firmware-misc-nonfree firmware-realtek`

Where can I find what HW drivers these packages contain and which package is needed for which model of RPi? I'm trying to strip down my image a bit to fit it in a 4GB mender.io A/B image that is only going to be used w/o most RPi HW (like display/GPU/camera/wifi). Possibly going to use BLE.

Update (for 3B+ and 4B):
It seems at first glance that atheros, libertas and realtek are Wifi drivers not used in 3B+ or 4B.
The firmware-brcm80211 seems to be Wifi/BLE CYW43455 drivers.
firmware-misc-nonfree: Misc fw binaries, not sure if needed.

Will try to build an image with only brcm80211 and hope that is enough for 3B+ and 4B devices.

Comment: The stock `/lib/firmware` directory is ~200 MB and `/lib/modules/x.x.x` is ~25MB  -- just pointing this out as even if you cut out 80% of that it may not be worth the time/hassle going forward.  Creating a 4GB image sans GUI shouldn't be hard; the current 64-bit lite version of RpiOS is <2GB.

Comment: I now, but for me it is a big percentage. A mender.io A/B image has two instances of the rootfs (for stable remote fw upgrades). Add ca 250MB /boot and a /data partition. And the fact that most 4GB SD cards are "much" smaller than 4GB. Then these 2*200MB is quite a lot ...

Comment: As goldilocks said this will save little space AND next time you upgrade the firmware will be restored. If you REALLY need to save space there are almost certainly programs you don't need.

Comment: NOTE a stock image actually contains 4 sets of modules e.g. /lib/modules/5.15.84-v8+ /lib/modules/5.15.84+ /lib/modules/5.15.84-v7+ /lib/modules/5.15.84-v7l+ depending of what models you use you could remove those for unused architectures (but they will reappear with upgrade)

Comment: As I said, we use mender.io for stable firmware upgrade, which is why we have two rootfs partitions (A/B swap). So we don't do any OS upgrades on device. By removing build-essentials, some -dev and firmware above I now got it down from 1.3GB to 850GB. That is a 2*450MB saving on a 4GB card ... firmware is a considerable part of this. Which leaves me with a /data partition 5 times larger than before.